# Hadoop "cd" (change directory command) doesn't work

Tags: hadoop, command

I am learning Hadoop. What an interesting world. Hats off to Tom White and all folks contributing to Apache Hadoop.

I was practicing hadoop commands like rmdir

$hadoop fs -rmdir hadoop-test1

It says directory not empty. 
So next obvious step would be to go to "hadoop-test1" directory and delete the contents in that directory.

So I tried to use linux "cd" command to go to "hadoop-test1" directory

It says there is not "cd" command.

Any reason why "cd" is not in hadoop?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Hadoop there is no cd command. If you want to delete a directory, try below code

`hdfs dfs -rm -r <path>`

Comment: I got that. But why don't they have "cd" command in hadoop? any reason?

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop use hdfs as its filesystem and there is no command "cd" in hdfs. See the below link...

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html

Answer (score 0):

The "cd" command isnt present in hadoop as HDFS is a virtual file system and do not represent actuall data locations. It is only an abstract representation of the file hierarchy.  Hence to change our current working directory to a virtual file and to work within it would not make sense.